# Creating a D3D device without HWND input parameter to MSFT CreateDevice() function

Tags: c++, directx, direct3d, directx-9, d3dx

Kindly Pardon me if my doubt is silly or foolish. I am totally new to DirectX programming. Just have C++ knowledge (Very basic COM knowledge).

Below code sample is from MSDN [Creating D3D device](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb219676%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) which explains how to create a D3D device from scratch.

**MyDoubt is** :

> Here the function "**pD3D->CreateDeviceEx()**" takes in a parameter
>   HWND hwnd. What if I am trying to create a D3D device from a
>   commadline C++ win32 app where I need to use some of the functions in D3D device's interfaces. How do I get the HWND field. In this case
>   how do I create D3D device. PLease explain in detail.

```
HRESULT InitD3D9Ex( /* IN */ HWND hWnd, /* OUT */ IDirect3DDevice9Ex ** ppD3DDevice )
{
    HRESULT hr = E_FAIL;
    IDirect3D9Ex * pD3D = NULL;
    IDirect3DDevice9Ex * pDevice = NULL;

    if(ppD3DDevice == NULL)
    {
        return hr;
    }

    // Create the D3D object, which is needed to create the D3DDevice.
    if(FAILED(hr = Direct3DCreate9Ex( D3D_SDK_VERSION, &pD3D )))
    {
        *ppD3DDevice = NULL;
        return hr;
    }


    // Set up the structure used to create the D3DDevice. 
    D3DPRESENT_PARAMETERS d3dpp; 
    ZeroMemory( &d3dpp, sizeof(d3dpp) );
    d3dpp.Windowed = TRUE;
    d3dpp.SwapEffect = D3DSWAPEFFECT_DISCARD;
    d3dpp.BackBufferFormat = D3DFMT_UNKNOWN;

    // Create the Direct3D device. 
    if( FAILED( hr = pD3D->CreateDeviceEx( D3DADAPTER_DEFAULT, D3DDEVTYPE_HAL, hWnd,
                                      D3DCREATE_SOFTWARE_VERTEXPROCESSING,
                                      &d3dpp, NULL, &pDevice ) ) )

    {
        *ppD3DDevice = NULL;
        return hr;
    }

    // Device state would normally be set here

    *ppD3DDevice = pDevice;

    return hr;
}
```

Comment: I've found very usefull [this web](http://www.directxtutorial.com/) to learn the firsts steps to configure and use DirectX.

Answer (score 3):

In Windows all the visual things are controlled by window handles. You cannot create the D3D "device" and attach it to "nothing". You must associate the "D3D device" with some window (your own one or a desktop).

Your console window is created by the system and you do not control its creation flags, so even if you use the [GetConsoleWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683175%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function, you cannot use this HWND in Direct3D device creation functions (this might have changed with the introduction of Aero).

You cannot avoid creating getting yet another window handle in your console application. Use the `RegisterWindowClass` and `CreateWindow` functions to create a new window or find the handle to your desktop (I doubt you would want that).